# Etherscan for Ropsten not showing tx events anymore

Tags: contract-debugging, events, etherscan, ropsten

Since today 2018-04-11 etherscan on Ropsten testnet does not show anymore the events related to a given transaction. It is very important for the testing and debugging of Smart Contract to view the events produced by a transaction.

So, my question is, do you know if the event view functionality is just temporarily disabled on etherscan or removed for ever? Thanks!